# How to set custom headers for Solrj 8.1 Http2SolrClient

Tags: java, solr, solrj

We are upgrading our app environment to use

```
Solr Server: 8.1.1
ZK: 3.4.14
Solr Client: SolrJ 8.1.1
```

With this update we are planning to use newly introduced `Http2SolrClient`; however this class does not provide any provision to pass custom headers. For example, how can I pass basic auth headers?